# Why can't I upload a image by Django?

Tags: html, django

I'm going to make a book bulletin board using the django and put a picture of the book in it and post a post.
But the text is going up, but the picture isn't going up.

i add
`MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')`
`MEDIA_URL = '/media/'` in settings.py

model.py

```py
class Book(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    title = models.TextField()
    author = models.TextField(max_length=50)
    content = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='image/',blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    like_user = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,related_name='like_book')
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

form.py

```py
class Book_Form(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ('title','author', 'content','image')
        widgets = {
            'title': forms.TextInput(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'form-control',
                    'placeholder': 'title'
                }
            ),
            'author': forms.TextInput(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'form-control',
                    'placeholder': 'author'
                }
            ),
            'content': forms.TextInput(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'form-control',
                    'placeholder': 'content',
                }
            ),
        }
```

create.html

```html
{% block content %}
  <form action="" method = 'POST' enctype="multipart/form-data" style= 'margin:40px; height:50px; width:80%;'>
    {% csrf_token %}
     {{form.as_p}}
    </div>
    <div class = "d-grid gap-2 col-4 mx-auto" style= 'margin:20px; height:50px;'>
      <input type="submit", class="btn btn-primary" value='제출'>
    </div> 
  </form>

{% endblock content %}
```

view.py

```py
@login_required
def create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        book = Book_Form(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if book.is_valid():
            book = book.save(commit=False)
            book.user = request.user
            book.save()
            return redirect('books:detail', book.pk)
    else:
        form = Book_Form()
    context = {
        'form': form, 
    }
    return render(request,'books/create.html',context)
```

If I try to add an image, DB does not store the image.

Is there something wrong with my settings? Or is there anything else I need to set up?

+
urls.py

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path ,include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('books/', include('books.urls'),),
    path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls'),),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

- 

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8aYm.png)

Comment: How does the database of the created book looks like, is the `image` column filled with some data?

Comment: The Image column in the DB is empty.
I will upload additional images.

Comment: If i put an image in the form and submit it,
There should be data in the image column, but it is empty. That's why it's a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried declaring the full path in your upload_to class attribute parameter?

For e.g:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    title = models.TextField()
    author = models.TextField(max_length=50)
    content = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='name_of_app/image/',blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    like_user = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,related_name='like_book')
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```